# Multiple clusters listening to the same JMS messaging queue

Tags: jakarta-ee, queue, jms, messaging, microservices

I've been searching for a JMS solution and I (surprisingly) haven't been able to find an easy answer.  I may be searching for the wrong thing, so hopefully the community on stackoverflow can help.

What I'm working should be pretty basic: Using JMS for event notification across clusters of microservices. The setup is simple.  Suppose I have 3 clusters, each with 3 instances all separate from each other running on their own EE server instances on different machines.

```
Cluster A
 A1, A2, A3

Cluster B
  B1, B2, B3

Cluster C
  B1, B2, B3
```

And I have a central JMS server which has a queue they all listen to:

```
A1, A2, A3 |
B1, B2, B3 |<-------> JMS Queue (Q1)
C1, C2, C3 |
```

Microservice instance A2 processes a request and publishes Message (M) onto (Q1).  What I want to happen is that for each of the other clusters - B,C - one instance in that cluster picks up the message and processes it for the cluster.  It obviously doesn't matter which instance picks it up as long as it is only processed one time per cluster.  So it would look like

```
A2 | ---> publish (M) ----> JMS Queue (Q1)


B2 |
   | <---- (M) <----- JMS Queue (Q1)
C1 |
```

This seems like a very common, almost default setup that everyone would need.  But so far what I've found with the way queues work is that once (M) get published to (Q1) then only one of B1,B2,B3,C1,C2,C3 will pick it up and process it and not one from each cluster like I'm looking for.  If I use a Topic, then every instance in every cluster would get a message so it doesn't seem like this is what I'm looking for either.

So that's it. Thoughts?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you were using Weblogic as your EE server and MDBs as your listener, then you can use Topics and specify 'One Copy per Application' to achieve what you want.  'https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e15493/dist_topics.htm#WLMDB10081

Answer (score 0):

We used topic to resolve this issue. So instead of JMS queue use JMS topic. Have all the web applications on all cluster subscribe to this topic. We also have a writer component so that all of them can write to the topic.

```
Cluster A:
webapp1 --> StatusTopic (JMS Topic)
webapp2 --> StatusTopic (JMS Topic)

Cluster B:
webapp1 --> StatusTopic (JMS Topic)
webapp2 --> StatusTopic (JMS Topic)
```

Answer (score 0):

refer this site:[jms-clustering-example](https://dzone.com/articles/jms-clustering-example)

as a solution we use

> ClusteredConnectionFactory

which help to make multiple consumers from the same queue(provide load balancing between consumer).

> java.naming.provider.url

on which we have to assign dynamic URLs of the consumers.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to address the situation I described above